# How to set OAuth2 authrorization header in Ajax/JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, oauth

I am trying to set the OAuth2 header for a REST PUT call. I have tested it in Chrome and IE, and Fiddler reports "No authorization header present" for either browser. 
I have verified that all of the variables have the correct values for my call:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + $var_accesstoken)
    },
    type: "PUT",
    url: $var_IMAP_server_addr,
    contentType: "application/json", 
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonobj)
});
```

I am also aware that I may set the OAuth header like this:

headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + $var_accesstoken}

Neither seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So have you checked if it actually was sent in the browser? What if you use `headers` instead of `beforeSend`?

Comment: I just saw this error message: "Origin http://localhost:8080 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header." I am testing on my own machine.

Comment: So it explains it - if you send a request to another domain - they must allow it with  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.